# Cross-Domain Ajax Calls and maintaining session on Google App Engine

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, session, gwt, cross-domain

I have recently worked through a bunch of kinks making cross-domain ajax calls to a GAE app and it is working beautifully, however, I am trying to set an http session id when making said service call and it is working fine, except that every time I perform the request, the session is null again. I'm assuming that this is because an ajax call and not making the request over http? How can I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session tracking is usually done with cookies.  If you are using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), then cookies are not included in the request by default.  In order to send cookies along with your request, add the following to your XmlHttpRequest:

```
var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
  xhr.withCredentials = "true";
}
```

Comment: That helps. I also had to set _Access-Control-Allow-Credentials_ to true. **It is still not saving the session** but I think this is a good step in the right direction.