# AppEngine Preserve User when Proxying Across Services/Domains

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, proxy

I'm building an application on AppEngine, and attempting to communicate with two other AppEngine services that I don't manage. These two services just provide JSON data, but they need to use the same user I have authenticated on my side (the applications are within the same org, but work on different subdomains).

I have a basic proxy working, using Flask and urllib.fetch, but I'm losing the user authenticated with AppEngine during the request.

Essentially, when using `google.appengine.api.users` I would like to ensure that both my site and the target side end up with the same value when calling `users.get_current_user()`. Currently, the call to `get_current_user` shows the relevant info on my side, but results in `None` on the destination side.

Is there a way to pass the user credentials in the header?

My urlfetch.fetch call is nothing special:

```
resp = urlfetch.fetch(url, method=urlfetch.GET,
                            headers=headers,
                            follow_redirects=False)
```

**Note** I'm omitting my actual header dict definition on purpose :)

This is a bit similar to [Cross-Domain Ajax Calls and maintaining session on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519479/cross-domain-ajax-calls-and-maintaining-session-on-google-app-engine?rq=1), but not the same, since I'm looking to do this all on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Different services (even within the same project on GAE) do not share information about the logged-in user. An (incredibly awkward) solution is to require login and redirect if not logged in in the app.yaml file of the service you're hitting. BUT you will still have to physically open a page of the service you're hitting (e.g `window.open("https://the-static-page-of-your-service.appspot.com")`) to ensure that the user is logged into that service. Note that you cannot put the static page in an iframe on your service's site (Google doesn't their login page to be inserted into sites like this) nor can you open this page as soon as your site loads (any decent browser will consider this a pop-up and block it.) The only work-around I can find is to pop open this window by user input, like a "login" button.

In essence, you can't really do what you want - I would look into other auth solutions.